# JavaFX, Select and Move Canvas image with mouse

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, java-8, mouseevent

I created ArrayList and draw it on canvas. Shape class contains it's position and draw method as well (using canvas). I created the mouse event to select a star and move by moving. while moving, the screen keeps refreshing. **The actual shape doesn't move on the canvas.** for the mouse event, I mainly referenced [Select and Move Canvas image with MouseEvent and MouseClicked in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42193899/select-and-move-canvas-image-with-mouseevent-and-mouseclicked-in-javafx) this post.

I have checked the coordinates in the shape object is certainly changing, and I also checked the screen keeps refreshing.

```java
    public class Drawing1 extends Application {
    
        public static final double WINDOW_WIDTH = 700;
        public static final double WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400;
        public static final double CANVAS_HEIGHT = 300;
    
        GraphicsContext gc;
        ArrayList<Star> stars = new ArrayList<Star>();
        double startX;
        double startY;
        Color stroke, fill;
    
        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
            GridPane root = new GridPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
            stage.setTitle("Drawing");
            stage.setScene(scene);
    
            // *** Canvas
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(WINDOW_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
            root.add(canvas, 0, 0, 3, 1);
            gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
            clear();
    
            // *** (trying) drag
            stars.add(new Star(gc, 100, 100, 100, 100, Color.BLACK, Color.AQUA));
            stars.add(new Star(gc, 150, 150, 100, 100, Color.BLACK, Color.YELLOW));
    
            canvas.setOnMouseClicked(e -> this.select(e));
            canvas.setOnMouseMoved(e -> {
                if (this.nowSelected) {
                    this.move(e, canvas);
                }
            });
    
            stage.show();
        }
    
        double mouse_x = 0.0;
        double mouse_y = 0.0;
        Star selectedStar;
        boolean nowSelected;
    
        public void select(MouseEvent e) {
            double temp_mouse_x = e.getSceneX();
            double temp_mouse_y = e.getSceneY();
    
            for (int i = stars.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                Star star = stars.get(i);
                double x_max = star.getX() + star.getWidth();
                double y_max = star.getY() + star.getHeight();
                nowSelected = temp_mouse_x >= star.getX() && temp_mouse_x <= x_max // x-area
                        && temp_mouse_y >= star.getY() && temp_mouse_y <= y_max; //y-area              
    
                this.mouse_x = temp_mouse_x;
                this.mouse_y = temp_mouse_y;
    
                if (!nowSelected) {
                    star.setSelected(false);
                } else if (star.isSelected() && nowSelected) { // deselect the circle if already selected
                    star.setSelected(false);
                    System.out.println(i + " index star deselected");
                } else {
                    star.setSelected(true);
                    System.out.println(i + " index star selected");
                    selectedStar = star;   // needs deselector for all the others
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    
        public void move(MouseEvent e, Canvas canvas) {
            selectedStar.setX(this.mouse_x);
            selectedStar.setY(this.mouse_y);
            redraw();
            this.mouse_x = e.getSceneX();
            this.mouse_y = e.getSceneY();
            System.out.println(selectedStar);
        }
    }
```

I want the selected shape would be moving with the mouse.
By the way, It actually selects the square area it is contained but not the actual area. Is there is a way to accurately select that is drawn on canvas, instead of using a Shape extended class?

Comment: Please post [mcve]

Comment: The primariy question is - why are you using the Canvas? The Canvas is just not made for such kind of things. If you'd use the scene graph instead you'd have everyting you need to accomplish your task.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had made it simpler by eliminating all irrelevant parts. I will be trying to be more concise! @mipa To be honest, I didn't know other things rather than canvas. I will figure it out. Thank you for your comment!